# LINQ to SQL decrypt value before populating object

Tags: c#, sql, linq, encryption

There is a field in one of my tables that is encrypted using

```
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(<passphrase>,<value>)
```

When the value is placed into the object the field is still encrypted so I can't do anything with it. I can't create a view or stored proc or any other item that decrypts the fields on the database because then it defeats the purpose of encrypting the fields. Is there a way of having the frame work run something like

```
DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(<passphrase>, <columnName>)
```

before assigning the value to the object?

Right now I'm Getting the data then calling ExecuteQuery to decrypt the value. and assigning that new value over the encrypted value on my data model class. It works but I was just wondering if it could be done automatically through some options I don't know about. I've tried searching but have not found anything.

Comment: How will you automatically know the `passPhrase` and the type to convert the clear `varbinary` too, or do you want to retrieve a `byte[]`?

Comment: I know the PassPhrase Right now I get the Decrypt the value calling ExecuteQuery with something like the following.

Comment: I know the PassPhrase Right now I get the Decrypt the value calling ExecuteQuery with something like the following.

    "Select CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('{0}', {1}) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS {2} FROM Table Whered PrimaryKey = {3}"

Where 0 = phassphrase, 1 = column, 2 = name of column returned, 3 = key to exact record i want to decrypt. So I"m getting the value now. Its just that it takes me an extra step. After the data is populated into the object from the database. I have to run an extra query to to get the decrypted values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As demonstrated by [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62778/4), the following SQL is perfectly effective,

```
SELECT
            E.[Key],
            CAST(
                      DecryptByPassPhrase(
                          'test',
                          E.[Encrypted])
                AS
                    varchar(8000)) [Clear],
            E.[Other]
    FROM
            [Example] E;
```

So use [this overload of ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) to do something like,

```
var examples = context.ExecuteQuery<Example>(
    @"SELECT
                E.[Key],
                CAST(
                          DecryptByPassPhrase(
                              @p0,
                              E.[Encrypted])
                    AS
                        varchar(8000)) [Clear],
                E.[Other]
        FROM
                [Example] E;",
    passPhrase);
```

to retrieve and decrypt your data in one call.

Comment: yeah I was just coming to the conclusion that I was going to have to run the ExecuteQuery and provide the query myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using linq-to-sql and that the table you are pulling from is structured like so:

```
+--------+---------------+
| UserId |   Passphrase  |
+--------+---------------+
|      1 | laskdfmlsadkf |
+--------+---------------+
```

With this information, you can apply the decrypt method during your select.

```
var password = "password";
var userId = 1;

var result = usertable.Where(c => c.UserId == userId).ToList()
.Select(t => new 
{
    Passphrase = DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(t.Passphrase)
}).First()

bool areSame = (password == result.Passphrase);
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to go back and try this. I hope to get some time here soon.

Comment: `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` is TSQL function, not a .Net one.

Comment: @Jodrell You would need to push the `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` stored procedure [in to your linq2sql model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399357%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so it would be useable from .NET code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, is that implied by this answer?

Comment: The `DecryptByPassphrase` function takes at least 2 parameters and returns some clear `varbinary`, not a passphrase for comparison with a password. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910.aspx