# How to use DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How to get the same result in LINQ with the SQL query below?

SQL:

```
select ID,Password, Name from Customers 
where Email = @Email 
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('MyKey', Password)) = @Password
```

I have written the syntax in C# as

Linq:

```
var customer = objDataContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email = strEmail 
                                                   && c.Password == strPasswd);
```

How to decrypt `c.Password` in linq syntax?

Comment: Is it Linq to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362381/linq-to-sql-decrypt-value-before-populating-object

Comment: btw, you should **never** store passwords in a database, even encrypted. You should only store a salted hash.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Thanks for your suggestion but my database had already been designed before I joined this project.